# How to deploy two react app the same url in Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, nginx, deployment

I have a system consisting of three parts:

1- NodeJS API

2- React APP1

3- React APP2 (seperate admin panel)

I am using nginx as a server and nodejs api running via pm2

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/APP1/dist/;

    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
    }

    location / {
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
    }
}
```

this nginx configration works proper NodeJS API and APP1 on main path. But when i try to run APP2 like domain.com/admin not working. I've tried like this configration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
    }

    location / {
            root /var/www/APP1/dist/;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
    }

    location /admin {
            root /var/www/APP2/dist/;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
    }
}
```

How can i run it properly?

Also when i try to alias instead root that time index.html loading but components not load.

Comment: I've tried but not related actually about that. Probably it's related about react router and react package.json some path things but I can not find any example on the google

Comment: Did you try to set the `basename` for the router?

Comment: no, how can i implement that. can u share any resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
  }

  location / {
    root /var/www/APP1/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
  }

  location /basename {
    alias /var/www/APP2/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
  }
}
```

AND FOR REACT ROUTER

```
  <BrowserRouter basename={basename}>
      <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```